# Using a class in ADT(abstract data types) or separate compilation in C++

Tags: c++, scope, compilation, adt

I just started using separate compilation and ADT so I created a project to understand how to create the different types of files. I have created three files
main.cpp (main file)

```
#include "Interface.h" //include header file
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    hello();
    User user1;
}
```

Interface.cpp (implementation file where functions go)

```
#include "Interface.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void hello()
{
 cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

Interface.h (header file where the class,defintions and data variables go)

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H
#include <string>

void hello();
class User
{
public:
    
    string name;
    int age;
};

#endif//INTERFACE_H
```

---

When I run the project it gives me the error:
**Build: Debug in FirstProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\FirstProject\main.cpp|14|error: 'User' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))**
and that's referring to the main.cpp where I created user1.
Can someone please show how I declare the User class in the main function.
I have copied and pasted the code directly from my code. This is everything from my project I created called FirstProject.

Comment: The only problem here is using `string` instead of `std::string`. The error mentioned in the question is not reproducible.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the actual code into the question, or did you (re)write it into the question? Check spelling (especially upper- versus lower-case) in your actual code.

Comment: And regarding the comment by @Evg, is the error you mention the *only* error you get? Please [edit] your question to include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste of the build output, as well as the command you use to build.

Answer (score -4):

You can replace with this:

```
          typedef struct User{
                       string name;
                       int age;
           }
```

Comment: No, C++ is not C. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: That isn't even syntactically valid in either C or C++.